# Modify inbuilt Java functions

Tags: java, function

Is it possible to change how functions inherent to java function without modifying the files? For example, I'd like to modify `java.util.Arrays.toString()` to throw an error if used on anything but a 1D array, for convenience. Is this possible?

Sorry if it's been asked before, couldn't find it on google. Thanks.

Comment: @JNYRanger: It's a static method...

Comment: Why should a `toString()` helper method _ever_ throw an exception? That seems like extremely user-unfriendly behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't do that. I suggest you write your own separate class, given that you want different functionality.

Obviously Java allows you to override non-final *instance* methods in classes, but even then the clients would need to know to create an instance of the subclass... and restricting the set of inputs that a method can accept is a breaking change anyway. And seeing as this is a static method in the first place... basically, the normal mechanisms for custom behaviour aren't going to help you.

Comment: Of course there's always runtime bytecode modification. But changing the Java library classes is the wrong thing to do in the first place, no matter how it's done.